# Как сделать таблицу с фиксированным (вертикально) хедером, чтобы при этом скролл был горизонтальный и вертикальный?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Делаю проект на реакте. Есть таблица, где очень много столбцов (около 17 штук), поэтому нужен горизонтальный скролл. Также много строк, поэтому скролл нужен и вертикальный. Если я засовываю таблицу в див где overflow auto, то как бы с одной стороны скроллы вертикальный и горизонтальный имеются по бокам и можно скроллить таблицу, но заголовок таблицы тоже скроллится, а он должен быть всегда виден.
Попробовал сделать отдельную таблицу для заголовков, отдельную для данных. Для таблицы данных скролл только по вертикали, а для дива, в котором эти две таблицы скролл по горизонтали. Но когда скроллю по горизонтали, то скроллится и вертикальный скроллбар (в смысле он скрывается вправо, если скроллить влево, что в принципе логично). Но мне надо было чтобы скроллбары всегда были видны, а также чтобы хедеры тоже были видны, при этом хедер по горизонтали должен прокручиваться, если я скроллю данные по горизонтали.

Comment: Обычными скроллами это не решить, придется вручную абсолютно позиционировать ячейки, что не самая тривиальная задача, особенно с ростом требований к таблице. Советую воспользоваться готовыми копонентами, вот очень хорошая библиотека: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: Спасибо, попробую